# retrofit sometimes not working when using in separate fragment in same activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fragment, retrofit2

I am just wondering, 
when I use retrofit in multiple fragments which belong to same activity sometimes one or more fragments have no response from retrofit callback.

I wrote Log in my code every request is sending but most of the times one of them will get error code 429 (too many requests) the funny part is when I debug my code everything is OK and every request in all fragments will get response

I used enqueue to send request

```
/**
   * Asynchronously send the request and notify {@code callback} of its response or if an error
   * occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.
   */
  void enqueue(Callback<T> callback);
```

so the request will run in another thread

any suggestion?

Comment: Invalid activicy lifecycle phase during response ?

Comment: @Antoniossss i think that should be onCreate because i wrote requests in onCreateView on fragments

Comment: You can put some log in your request and response.
Instead of breakpoints.
Also if possible share some codeblock for better understanding.

Comment: I doubd that you will get response in onCreate